# Select all records where a relationship count is zero using Eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

In plain English: I have three tables. `subscription_type` which has many `email_subscription`s which has many `email`s.

I'm trying to select all `email_subscription` records that have a particular `subscription_type`, that also don't have any associated `email` records that have a `status` of `Held`.

The particular bit I am stuck on is only returning `email_subscriptions` which have zero `emails` (with an additional where clause stacked in there described above).

Using Eloquent, I've been able to get a bit of the way, but I don't have any idea how to select all the records that have a relationship count of zero:

```
$subscriptionsWithNoCorrespondingHeldEmail = EmailSubscriptions::whereHas('subscriptionType', function($q) {
            $q->where('name', 'New Mission');
        })-; // What do I chain here to complete my query?
```

Additionally, is this even possible with Eloquent or will I need to use Fluent syntax instead?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `has()` method to query the relationship existence:

```
has('emails', '=', 0)
```

Eg:

```
$tooLong = EmailSubscriptions::whereHas('subscriptionType', function($q) {
    $q->where('name', 'New Mission');
})->has('emails', '=', 0)->get();
```

**Edit**

You can do more advanced queries with the `whereHas()` and `whereDoesntHave()` methods:

```
$tooLong = EmailSubscriptions::whereHas('subscriptionType', function($q) {
    $q->where('name', 'New Mission');
})
->whereDoesntHave('emails', function ($query) {
    $query->where('status', '=', 'whatever');
})->get();
```

Comment: How do I also add an additional where statement onto this? For example, I only want to check if the count of emails on that relation that *has a specific status* is 0.

Comment: This is my answer, thanks! Looks like I can avoid the relationship count `has` method entirely and just do a whereDoesntHave() call.

Answer (score 0):

OK what I have under stand from your Question is you would like to have a All Emails which have

> specific subscription_type, Zero(0) association and status = status

If yes so you canuse array in where statement.
Like:

```
        $q->->where(array('status' => 'status','subscription_type'=>'what ever you want));
```